# The "Create free Team" form displays my old display name

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams, display-names

When I visit the [Create free Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/create/free) page, I see one of my old display names automatically filled in the form. **Why is that information still being used?**

Demo:

[image: "Create free Team" form]

A couple of notes:

- That name is not even my previous display name. I believe it was my first if I'm not mistaken.
- The private field "Full name" (AKA, "real name") is blank for me and I've never used that display name as my full/real name.

I still see that old display name in the form. Can it please be removed?

Comment: Did you fill that in your "Private information (not shown publicly)
, full name" section? Mine shows my full legal name.

Comment: No, I did not. My "Full Name" field on my profile is empty. That was a previous Display Name of mine.

Comment: you don't have a developer story, right? It can pull old names from there as well.

Comment: @rene I've disabled the developer story tab a while ago but the name on my developer story is the same as my current display name anyway.

Comment: I recall a comment or an answer from an SE dev that some field that still exists in the datamodel but it isn't shown to users anymore still either holds or gets populated in some error conditions and then in another loophole that deprecated field gets somehow used as the single truth. I can't find the source of that anymore. Let's hope a dev can shine a light on this.

Comment: @Makyen I can no longer reproduce this issue, so I'm fine with the question being closed. But I'm wondering if questions about the link on the sidebar (which is still there) are also off-topic now? I missed the announcement/discussion of that new close reason. Assuming there's one, I'd appreciate it if you can point me to it.

Comment: There wasn't discussion on MSO about topicality for Stack Overflow for Teams. That Teams support is off-topic on all public meta sites is a directive from the company. They want people to be using their support portal for Teams support at all levels. While we plan to have a FAQ post here on MSO, we don't have one yet. The best information I have for you is in [answer to: "With Stack Overflow Teams moved, where do Meta questions about it belong?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385134/271271), including the edit done by Juice, an SE staff member.

Comment: When closing, I quickly debated between "no repo" and "is Teams" as a reason. I'm fine with either one. I didn't pick "no repo", because I didn't actually go through the entire process, including that the link in the sidebar, as expected, now loads a page on a non-SO-public site. Effectively, picking "is Teams" was just easier. If the sidebar link was opening something on SE/SO public Q&A site pages, then I'd say, yes, such a question is on-topic, but it's just a link to another site at this point.